# Error during deploy a web application (react+express+mongo) in a Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, backend, devops, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04

I am facing critical issues to deploy a web application in a Ubuntu Server from Digital Ocean and your support is very welcome.

I've set up an Ubuntu 20.04 (x64) server with default configurations and no firewall. On Ubuntu, I installed Node.js version 14.18.3 and set up a React frontend on port 3000 and an Express backend on port 3333. Additionally, I installed MongoDB version 4.4. Both environments are running simultaneously using pm2. While accessing the address on port 3000, the frontend displays the expected login screen, indicating it's responding correctly. However, the backend is not working as expected. To isolate the problem and eliminate the possibility of any issues between frontend and backend, I used Postman to test the direct connection to the backend, persisting the problem (commands below):

```
--header 'x-company-id: 1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "password": "123"
}
```

I encountered errors such as ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

Important points:

- Locally on my computer, the system runs well.
- No port blocking issues were identified as I have an internal route where accessing `http://<ip address>:3333/ping` should respond with "pong," and it is responding correctly.
- If I run `curl http://<ip address>:3333/` the response is `Found. Redirecting to /`

The latest error I am encountering is:

```
6|backend  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
6|backend  | npm ERR! errno 137
6|backend  | npm ERR! node-api-dpo@1.0.0 start: `babel-node -- index.js`
6|backend  | npm ERR! Exit status 137
6|backend  | npm ERR! 
6|backend  | npm ERR! Failed at the node-api-dpo@1.0.0 start script.
6|backend  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
6|backend  | 
6|backend  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
6|backend  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-12-09T15_18_09_271Z-debug.log
6|backend  | (node:49419) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.
6|backend  | 
6|backend  | Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
6|backend  | For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
6|backend  | (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

When I run `npm start` instead of using pm2 I receive the following error message:

```
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error during decryption (probably incorrect key). Original error: Error: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error
    at NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.$$decryptKey (/root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js:301:19)
    at NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.decrypt (/root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js:249:21)
    at Utils.decrypt (/root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/src/utils/utils.js:454:24)
    at /root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/src/oauth/services.js:48:26
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3932:16)
    at /root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3934:13)
    at /root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /root/compassDPO/climby_api_DPO/service/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-api-dpo@1.0.0 babel-node: `babel-node --presets=latest "index.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-api-dpo@1.0.0 babel-node script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-12-10T12_30_45_631Z-debug.log
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Before any update suggestion: Unfortunatelly I cannot update my nodejs, react, mongo or any other part of the system because it is a huge legacy system and it implies in a lot of work and time.

I have already:

- Initiate a complete new server (twice);
- Installed the dependencies;
- Checked if there is any blocking for the port 3333;
- As commented before, in my local computer system works well;
- Checked my Mongo access (it is up and running);
- Checked my .pem file

I don´t know what else to check. Do you have any suggestion or experience on this issue?

PS: Please let me know in case you need any test from my side and I will be happy to share additional information

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try deploying a simple web app and see how it works. Then incremental to db connect to a default app.  Then compare your code why its doing multiple redirect. Later add more app logs and see.

Comment: Thanks @Senthil, do you mean to deploy a simple web app in a different server?

Comment: In the same server, to isolate the problem. Is it your code is causing an issue - having the multiple redirects. Just rename your folder with some suffix of the files you deployed on the server .

Comment: eXAMPLE OPEN SOURCE APP : https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-nodejs this can be uploaded to your server and test it . Similarly take a db driven, then compare or check the app logs why we are getting multiple redirects.

Comment: Thanks @Senthil! It seems the issue is related to decrypting the pem key. I have tested doing ´´´GET´´´ to the server and it works well. But  when I go for a ´´´POST´´´ (login for example) it returns the error about decrypting (listed above). Inside my enviroment variables I am using the following address: `` ´´´CERT_RSA=/root/APP/Backend/service/climb.pem´´´ and this is my address to my mongodB in the server ´´´MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo´´´ (I am using localhost because my Mongo is in the same server as the backend).
Any additional thoughts.

Comment: check this forum https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22792. You might be missing the oaepHash in the parameter setting.